# group by 5 years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, indexed by year, month and day. Other fields are total_spending and total_earning.
I need to find out highest_earning and highest_spending in each year and then have to find mean of highest_earning and and mean of higest_spending in every 5 years.

I am getting hard time on how find mean of those 2 field for every 5 years

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your DataFrame?

Comment: What does every 5 years mean? Is it always even years, like [2000-2005), [2005-2010), or do you want 5 years from the first year in your data?

Comment: example :2001-2005, 2006-2010 etc

Comment: Can you share the Dataframe and expected output?